# how to get the address of a range to a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that gives an address to an excel range that is active and selected. I am trying to get it as a string.

```
Sub getRange()
Dim atcSheet As Worksheet
Dim selRange As Range
Dim myRange As String

Set actSheet = ActiveSheet
Set selRange = Selection

MsgBox (selRange.Address)
myRange = selRange.Address(RowAbsolute, ColumnAbsolute)
MsgBox (myRange)
end sub
```

When running this (after having selected a few cells making a range), MsgBox returns the address, but i could not make it in a variable as a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to get the absolute reference of the range into an string variable, this will do

```
myRange = selRange.Address
```

Address(True, True) is by default.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
myRange = selRange.Address(True, True)
' for debug
MsgBox myRange
```